# Time out on file upload (Item Added event) for files above around 200kb - 400kb

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload

When a item is added, i got to upload this item added to document library to a asp.net site, now i have done alll authentications just need to upload file, code i am using is only uploading files upto 200kb other then that it times out.

```
SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;   //item added properties
byte[] myByteArray = file.OpenBinary();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);

try
{
    uint myCopyUint = SharePointCopy.CopyIntoItems(Source, DestinationURL,
        myFieldInfoArray, myByteArray, out result);
}
catch (SoapException exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
}
```

I am using SharePoint copy web services.

Comment: Are you getting an error? can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Nope, there is no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line :

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
```

Waiting one minute before opening the file can be the cause of your timeout